# Azure health service always return available when my web app is stopped

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

i am developing a dashboard which checks for the health of the services , in my case i have a sample web app which is stopped since 30 min still Azure health servie API is showing it available is there any other approach to know the status or i am doing it wrong any helo will be really appreciated

Comment: I think you should mention the API you're using. Also, when the API shows the app is available, does the portal also show the same? Or it's stopped? You can check the activity logs to see if the request has been completed or it's still ongoing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Microsoft Azure Service Health is your personalized dashboard in the
> Azure portal for receiving notifications, guidance, and technical
> support when Azure service issues, updates, or planned maintenance
> affect your Azure resources.

Source: https://azure.microsoft.com/pt-br/resources/videos/azure-service-health-overview/

In other words, Azure Health Service is related to monitor downtime/scheduled maintenance on Azure infrastructure. When monitoring your APIs, you need to code you own health check mechanism. Here's a sample for Azure Functions:

https://medium.com/microsoftazure/azure-health-checks-via-csharp-35ce1d5b7c6f

Comment: Thank you for the comment and clarification @Thiago I figured that after bit struggle :) also i am exploring the possibility of the using availability with URL ping tests from appinsights  ,alerts and azure functions to manage this whole work flow